# Последовательное непрерывное воспроизведение аудио на странице с несколькими плеерами

Tags: javascript, html5, web-audio

[Есть страница](http://elenaturkka.ru/audio13c.htm), на ней плееры (Flash) из сервиса Uppod, но не во всех браузерах они проявляются, а главное их не видно в мобильных устройствах.
Решил заменить их на HTML5 audio, но не могу найти решение непрерывного, последовательного воспроизведения, когда после завершения проигрывания одного плеера начинает звучать следующий, [к примеру,](http://elenaturkka.ru/5ma/ma.html) или [тут](http://elenaturkka.ru/4ajs/ajs.htm).
Есть варианты плееров с плейлистами, но мне хотелось бы несколько плееров на странице, между которыми будет текст.

```js
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
for (let i = 0; i < audio.length; i++) {
  audio[i].addEventListener('ended', function() {
    if (audio[i].duration === audio[i].currentTime) {
      audio[i + 1].play();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div> 
<audio id="player2" preload="yes" controls style="width:500px;"> 
<source src="http://elenaturkka.ru/audio/iodin.mp3"; type="audio/mp3"> 
</audio> 
</div>

<div> 
<audio id="player3" preload="yes" controls style="width:500px;"> 
<source src="http://elenaturkka.ru/audio/iodin.mp3"; type="audio/mp3"> 
</audio> 
</div>
```

Comment: И у тебя этот код не работает?

Comment: Нет, не работает :((

Comment: Не знаю, у меня все работает

Comment: можешь тут проверить, все работает

Comment: Спасибо! действительно работает. Не работало потому, что скрипт стоял перед тегом </head>. После переноса в конец страницы, заработало. А еще почему писал ранее, что не работало, потому что кликал по кнопкам play\stop, и плееры все играли одновременно, думал, что твой скрипт будет вести себя так же, как на этой странице http://elenaturkka.ru/audio13c.htm  там при клике на один плеер, играющий останавливается и запускается кликнутый, но там флэш плееры, а они в мобильных устройствах не играют, вот теперь с вашей помощью заменю на html5 audio, Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста))

Comment: А можно задам вопрос?  Есть ли подобное решение для такого варианта - http://elenaturkka.ru/3pl/3players.htm? На компьютере плееры передают эстафету друг другу, а в мобильных устройствах нет.  Кстати, ваш код в этом варианте и на компьютере не работает.

Comment: У тебя семь пятниц на неделе, то работает то не работает... И кстати, в примере по ссылке не мой вариант скрипта....

Comment: Твой скрипт работает в другом примере, с другим плеером, а в этом варианте не работает. Я имел глупость, прочтя твоё "всегда пожалуйста", задать вопрос о возможности непрерывного воспроизведения еще и в этом варианте.  Считай, что я его не задавал.

Comment: ))) Да все ок...

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы проигрывались несколько плееров подряд, за это отвечает событие `ended`.
Надо его отследить и все. Мне кажется данная конструкция на столько проста, что и пояснять тут нечего

```js
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
for (let i = 0; i < audio.length; i++) {
  audio[i].addEventListener('ended', function() {
    if (audio[i].duration === audio[i].currentTime) {
      audio[i + 1].play();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<audio src="http://elenaturkka.ru/audio/iodin.mp3" controls></audio>
<audio src="http://elenaturkka.ru/audio/delight.mp3" controls></audio>
<audio src="http://elenaturkka.ru/audio/ots.mp3" controls></audio>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, но, к сожалению, не работает, вот примеры: http://elenaturkka.ru/4ajs/ajs.htm ;  http://elenaturkka.ru/5ma/ma.html

Comment: @Аркадий, ты мне лучше код покажи

Comment: вот код:

<script>
    var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");

    for (let i = 0; i < audio.length; i++) {
      audio[i].addEventListener('ended', function() {

        if (audio[i].duration === audio[i].currentTime) {
          audio[i + 1].play();
        }
      });
    }
</script>

</head>

код, размещенный после <body> не влезает
после публикации код потерял форматирование и размиестился сплошной строкой, как исправить, не знаю

Comment: вот в HTML:
            <div>
                <audio id="player2" preload="yes" controls style="width:500px;">
                    <source src="http://elenaturkka.ru/audio/iodin.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
                </audio>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div>
                <audio id="player3" preload="yes" controls style="width:500px;">
                    <source src="http://elenaturkka.ru/audio/delight.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
                </audio>
            </div> и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю нужно поработать с events. То есть запустить проигрывание на первом плеере, затем когда произойдет событие  'ended' запускай второй плеер , и так далее. Например:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let allAudio = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('audio'));
  allAudio[0].play();
  allAudio.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.addEventListener('ended', (ev) => {
      if (index === allAudio.length - 1) {
        index = 0
      } else {
        index++;
      }
      allAudio[index].play();
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<audio id="player2" preload="yes" controls style="width:500px;">
<source src="http://elenaturkka.ru/audio/iodin.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<audio id="player3" preload="yes" controls style="width:500px;">
<source src="http://elenaturkka.ru/audio/delight.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<audio id="player4" preload="yes" controls style="width:500px; ">
<source src="http://elenaturkka.ru/audio/ots.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Пускай не самый лучший код, но думаю концепция понятна.
Для первоначального запуска первого плеера можно использовать уже, что душе угодно.
Ниже ссылка на видео , аудио события:

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Comment: спасибо, но, к сожалению, не работает, вот примеры: http://elenaturkka.ru/4ajs/ajs.htm ; http://elenaturkka.ru/5ma/ma.html

Comment: посмотрю ближе к ночи

Comment: спасибо! у нас в Хабаровске уже ночь :)

Comment: переписан, на сто процентов рабочий вариант. Автостарт можно закомментировать, если не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо за внимание к проблеме и ваше время!  Однако все плееры по-прежнему играют одновременно:  http://elenaturkka.ru/5ma/ma.html

Comment: я просто на указанной странице запустил выше указанный свой JS code  , и все работает нормально, трэки переходят , одновременно ничего не включается. Как инициализируешь сво1й код? где он находится?

Comment: да, и два скрипта, которые ты указад в html, они не загружаются -статус у них 404. смотри почему скрипт ru.js  и de=mo.js не загружены

Comment: спасибо!  2 последних скрипта - мусор, забыл удалить. 

как инициализирую 1й код? в коде страницы я в точности повторил твой код let allAudio и т.д.  Но пока воз и ныне там, все проигрывается одновременно

Comment: короче , у тебя проблема в том что скрипт инициализируется раньше чем рендерится html, соответственно нету для js никаких audio. перенеси тег script вниз, перед закрывающимсся тегом body, и добавь весь js в document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{ //сюда добавь код что я написал})

Comment: все сделал так, как ты указал:   http://elenaturkka.ru/5ma/ma.html 
но пока ничего не изменилось, спасибо!

Comment: Аркадий, вы пользовались когда нибудь дебагером? он пишет когда не хватает скобок например, или другие ошибки показывает.. я уже добавил полностью рабочее приложение к себе в код. посмотрите.. все работает.(немного злой))))))

Comment: все сделал так, как ты указал, спасибо!  сначала было разочаровался, поскольку проверял, щелкая по иконкам play , stop , ну а случайно дождался, когда первый плеер закончит играть и увидел, что второй автоматически вступил в действие, думал, что твой скрипт будет управялть проигрыванием так же, как на этой странице - http://elenaturkka.ru/audio13c.htm Там, когда щелкаешь по одному плееру, играющий останавливается, спасибо!!!  я программист никакой, но вот сайт этот сделал (http://elenaturkka.ru/)

Comment: я вручную увидел, что пропустил две скобки, фигурную и простую, а дебаггером не пользовался, спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Сергей, не сердись, плииз!  Глянь на досуге недавно сделанный мной фильм https://youtu.be/ftFkKE98yms

Comment: карму мне в плюс))))) и тебе за фильм тоже)))