# Как проиграть 12 коротких аудиофайлов поочередно при клике на блок?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, аудио

Использую такой вариант,но тут проигрывается один аудиофайл, а хочу сделать, чтобы последовательно от 1 до 12 проигрывались

```
<a href="#" id="myLink" onclick="playAudio();"></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function playAudio(){
        var myAudio = new Audio;
        myAudio.src = "audio/smoke-on-the-water-1.mp3";
        myAudio.play();
    }
    jQuery(function() {
        $('#myLink').click(function(){
            playAudio();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/773505/Последовательное-непрерывное-воспроизведение-аудио-на-странице-с-несколькими-пле/773542#773542

Comment: если ответ Вам помог, пожалуйста отметьте его решением. Для этого нажмите на серую галку слева от текста ответа. Галка станет зеленой, что будет означать, что ответ принят и является решением

Answer (score 2):

**1. Вариант на jquery**

```js
$("audio").on('ended', function() {
  if ($(this).duration === $(this).currentTime) {
    if ($(this).is(':last-child')){
      $("audio").first().get(0).play();
    }
    else{
      $(this).next("audio").get(0).play();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <audio src="audio1.mp3" controls></audio>
  <audio src="audio2.mp3" controls></audio>
  <audio src="audio3.mp3" controls></audio>
</div>
```

**2. Вариант на js** - [такой же ответ предоставлен ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/773542/191745) [@Air](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211549/air)

```js
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
for (let i = 0; i < audio.length; i++) {
  audio[i].addEventListener('ended', function() {
    if (audio[i].duration === audio[i].currentTime){
      if (i < audio.length - 1){
        audio[i + 1].play();
      } 
      else{
        audio[0].play();
      }

    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div>
  <audio src="audio1.mp3" controls></audio>
  <audio src="audio2.mp3" controls></audio>
  <audio src="audio3.mp3" controls></audio>
</div>
```

**UPD 1:** *добавлено цикличное воспроизведение, после воспроизведения последнего файла проигрывается первый и далее "по кругу" заново.*

---

**UPD 2:** - по выясненному условию *при нажатии на любую точку блока должно производиться воспроизведение следующего файла (см. п.3)*.

**3. Вариант 1 v.2** - *при нажатии на любую точку блока производится воспроизведение следующего файла*.

```js
var last_play = 0;

$(".block").on("click", function() {
  if (last_play == $("audio").length) {
    last_play = 0;
  }
  $("audio").eq(last_play).get(0).play();
  last_play++;
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <audio src="audio1.mp3" controls></audio>
  <audio src="audio2.mp3" controls></audio>
  <audio src="audio3.mp3" controls></audio>
</div>
```

**UPD 3:** - *добавлена проверка на завершение воспроизведения предыдущего файла (см. п.4)*.

**4. Вариант 1 v.3.1:** - *сравниваем `duration` и `currentTime`*

```js
var last_play = 0;

$(".block").on("click", function() {
  if (last_play == $("audio").length) {
    last_play = 0;
  }
  if(last_play > 0 && $("audio").eq(last_play - 1).get(0).duration == $("audio").eq(last_play - 1).get(0).currentTime) {
    $("audio").eq(last_play).get(0).play();
    last_play++;
  }
  else if(last_play == 0 && ($("audio").eq(last_play).get(0).currentTime === 0 || $("audio").eq(last_play - 1).get(0).duration == $("audio").eq(last_play - 1).get(0).currentTime)) {
    $("audio").eq(last_play).get(0).play();
    last_play++;
  }
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <audio src="audio1.mp3" controls></audio>
  <audio src="audio2.mp3" controls></audio>
  <audio src="audio3.mp3" controls></audio>
</div>
```

**4. Вариант 1 v.3.2:** - *проверяем свойство `paused`*

```js
var last_play = 0;
var prev_play = 0;

$(".block").on("click", function() {

  if (last_play == $("audio").length) {
    last_play = 0;
  }
  if (last_play == 1) {
    prev_play = 0;
  }

  if ($("audio").eq(prev_play).get(0).paused) {
    $("audio").eq(last_play).get(0).play();
    prev_play = last_play;
    last_play++;
  }
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <audio src="audio1.mp3" controls></audio>
  <audio src="audio2.mp3" controls></audio>
  <audio src="audio3.mp3" controls></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73637/discussion-on-answer-by-alex---12----).